# How to install upper driver for class?

Tags: windows, filter, driver, wdk, inf

I created a filter driver and I just want to install it for the Serial port. I know that the existing driver class is "Ports" so I changed inf file as follows:

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=Ports
ClassGUID={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%Provider%
DriverVer=03/17/2001,1.0.0.1
CatalogFile=KmdfSamples.cat
```

Note that the classguid is the same as in system for serial port. So I does not know how to install it for specyfic class, I have to manally edit "UpperFilter" field in registry?

I also can not find out from the microsoft documentation if I have to specyfi device in such a way (I do not know the device name, but i know whole class id).

So the questions are:

- How to install upper filter for existing class?
- Have I specyfi the device hardware id that I do not know?

Any repsonses will be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: look for example [moufiltr.HW.AddReg](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/input/moufiltr/moufiltr.inx#L78) also search [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/inf-addreg-directive) for `UpperFilters` and `LowerFilters` keywords

Comment: I found it before, but there are sections like ;
HID\VID_045E&PID_001E.DeviceDesc = "Shiny Things Firefly Mouse"
HID\VID_045E&PID_0029.DeviceDesc = "Shiny Things Firefly Mouse"
HID\VID_045E&PID_0039.DeviceDesc = "Shiny Things Firefly Mouse"
HID\VID_045E&PID_0040.DeviceDesc = "Shiny Things Firefly Mouse"
HID\VID_045E&PID_0047.DeviceDesc = "Shiny Things Firefly Mouse"
And i don know if that HID\ has to be a concrete device or i can set it random.

Comment: in general you need `HKR,,UpperFilters,0x00010000,your-service-name`

Comment: under this key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` set `UpperFilters` `REG_MULTI_SZ` add your-service-name

Comment: Ok, I understand. [My try](http://pastebin.com/AkGqkqm9), I installed it by right-clik -> install, and windows then says it succeed, but any UpperFilter  key was not added in ` HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4‌​d36e978-e325-11ce-bf‌​c1-08002be10318}`, So the only option is to add this entry manually?

Comment: Should I specify insted of  HID\Vid_045E&Pid_001E "*PNP0501" ?

Comment: I also tried doing it this way: [Firefly_Inst_HWAddReg.NT]
HKLM,SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4‌​d36e978-e325-11ce-bf‌​c1-08002be10318},"UpperFilters",0x00010000,"Firefly" but this also do not give any results

Comment: `I installed it by right-clik -> install` - this will be not work of course. this exec `InfDefaultInstall.exe your.inf` or `setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall` because your inf have not [DefaultInstall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/inf-defaultinstall-section) section - nothing will be processes

Comment: and `$ARCH$` this must not be in final `inf` file, this for [INX Files to Create INF Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/wdf/using-inx-files-to-create-inf-files)